# New channel in TG

Tags: help, startup

I'm not native speaker, so sorry for my english
My story is long, but qustion is short, so i combine it: in my oppinion, anonymity is realy important now, but a lot of people ignore it, cause think, that its hard to use soft. I want to help with popularization ideas of TOR in RU segment in Telegram. Its possible with news, information about easy ways to secure personal data. And here is two But:
1)I'm not expert in IT, so original content from me not included
2)I'm not good in other languages
But in other hand:
1)I'm sceptic and and analysist a bit, so always(when its important) when i find new info, i try to check it(Panorama taught me that)
2)Even i cant understand something(novel in other language or spec info), i am not stop, i am trying to find another еxplanation

So, im thought, i need some advises about good sourses(yep, im entusiast, who want to start without good experience)

Comment: Be familiar on using Linux environments https://linuxjourney.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot here so I am going to focus on this comment because I think this is what you are asking, "I want to help with popularization ideas of TOR in RU segment in Telegram."

The most important thing is to help people understand [what is Tor](https://2019.www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en) and [how is it used](https://2019.www.torproject.org/about/torusers.html.en)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm from Russia too - and that's totally not a problem to read Tor's basic documentation on torproject.org website having just 8th grade school english level, so don't worry. Helping others without technical knowledge is impossible in matters like this: you have to see the technical background for every problem you're asked about, and that's a mandatory demand, because you can physically solve the problem with technical mistakes and pitfalls and you will hurt the privacy badly. And - speaking about Russia - this can have a big consequences in a matter of personal security